# rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0 error occured TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queue_size'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm following [rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello World](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World) and when runing `rosserial_python` `serial_node.py` using `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0` then got problems

```
ling@ubuntu12:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1447168684.001756] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1447168684.011288] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ling/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py", line 80, in <module>
    client = SerialClient(port_name, baud)
  File "/home/ling/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 333, in __init__
    self.pub_diagnostics = rospy.Publisher('/diagnostics', diagnostic_msgs.msg.DiagnosticArray, queue_size=10)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queue_size'
```

I tried to ignored the error and start the next step

```
ling@ubuntu12:~/catkin_ws$ rostopic echo chatter
```

It wouldn't work as I thought:

```
WARNING: topic [/chatter] does not appear to be published yet
```

I'm using groovy on ubuntu12 but my arduino IDE is installed on Win7. Does it matter?

Can someone help? Thanks advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220708/rosrun-rosserial_python-serial_node.py-/dev/ttyacm0-error-occured-typeerror:-__init__()-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-%27queue_size%27/) by [Gure Ling](https://answers.ros.org/users/24532/gure-ling/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a mismatch between your version of ROS and the version of rosserial that you're using.

The `queue_size` option was added to rospy in ROS Hydro, and it seems like you're running an earlier version of ROS.

You should check out the branch of rosserial for the version of ROS that you're using; for example if you're using ROS Groovy, you should check out the `groovy-devel` branch of rosserial.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gure Ling](https://answers.ros.org/users/24532/gure-ling/) on 2015-11-11**:
Yes I think you are right. I've tried that wiki on Indigo and worked fine. Thank you very much.